# Magento2 email is printing Html tags

Tags: magento2, email-templates

I have custom email. I have passed HTML inside variable as follows.

But the issue is it is printing HTML instead of table

```
public function getTable()
    {

        $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
        // echo "<pre>";
        // print_r($data);
        // die();
        $size = substr_count($data['product_id'],',') + 1;
        $tot_arr = array();
        $value = array();
        $title = array();
        $first_spt = explode(',', $data['optiontitle']);
        $first_spt_val = explode(':', $data['optionvalue']);
        // for ($i=0; $i < 2; $i++) { 
        //     $tot_arr[$i]['title'] = explode('@@', $key);
        // }
        foreach ($first_spt as $key) {
            $title[] = explode('@@', $key);
        }


        foreach ($first_spt_val as $key => $val) {
            $searchForValue = ',';
            if( strpos($val, $searchForValue) !== false ) {
                $str_arr = preg_split ("/\,/", $val);  
                foreach ($str_arr as $str_arrkey) {
                    //echo $key;die;
                    $value[$key][] = explode('@@', $str_arrkey);
                }
            }else{
                $value[] = explode('@@', $val);
            }

        }


        $html = "<table>";

        $new  = array();
       for ($i=0; $i < $size; $i++) { 

            $html .= "<tr>";

            // $title[$i] = isset($title[$i]) ? $title[$i] : null;

            foreach ($title[$i] as $col) {
            $html .= "<th>" . $col . "</th>";
            }

            $html .= "</tr>";  
            $html .= "<tr>";
            // echo "<pre>";
            // print_r($value);
            // die();

            if ($this->contains_array($value[$i]) == 'true') {
                foreach ($value[$i] as $key) {
                    $html .= "<tr>";
                    $new = array_slice($key, 1, -1);
                    foreach ($new as $col) {
                        $html .= "<td>" . $col . "</td>";   
                    }
                    $html .= "</tr>";   
                }             
            }else{
                $new = array_slice($value[$i], 1, -1);
                foreach ($new as $col) {
                    $html .= "<td>" . $col . "</td>";   
                } 
            }


            $html .= "</tr>"; 

           //$value[$i]
       }

        $html .= "</table>";
         // echo "<pre>";
         //    print_r($html);
         //    die();
        return $html;
    }
```

For call this in templateoptions variable I have addded

```
$optionTitle = $this->getTable();
```

Output is like

[image]

I need to print table & not table tags

My type is HTML in email_templates.xml

Template HTML I have added

```
 <td colspan="2" valign="top" style="font-size:12px;padding:7px 9px 9px 9px;border:1px solid #EAEAEA;">
                                                {{var optionTitle}}<br></n>
                                                {{var optionValue}}
                                            </td>
```

Comment: please share your html file.

Comment: have you tried getChildHtml() ?

Comment: I have added the file in ques

Answer (score 2):

I got an answer to my own question, just posting it as it might help someone.

Need to add `|raw`

```
<td colspan="2" valign="top" style="font-size:12px;padding:7px 9px 9px 9px;border:1px solid #EAEAEA;">
   {{var optionTitle|raw}}<br></n>
   {{var optionValu|raw}}
</td>
```